# Can GDAL read/write Geopackage on RAM instead of disk?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, fiona

I am working on a Python project that makes extensive use of GDAL's Geopackage vector and raster drivers. Since geopackage is essentially SQLite, I also use the Python SQLite library to do lots of other table manipulations on the same database. I know that SQLite allows you work with a database that exists in memory instead of on the disk, and I'm wondering if it would be possible to use GDAL to interact with the database while it is still in memory instead of passing it C:/[path].gpkg

I'm thinking my project would run a lot faster and look a little cleaner if I could do all the intermediate operations on a database that exists in memory, then write a geopackage to the disk at the end.

Comment: Maybe it is possible, have a look at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6150#no1

Comment: Even though I don't usually work with Windows. I think you could create a folder that stores data inside RAM memory as explained here: https://superuser.com/a/217762/1246357. Then instead of doing extra configurations, you'd just put your data inside this RAM disk and use GDAL as you'd normally do on your disk.